# How to align views to right of the screen and to left of widhtest view?

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I want to have textviews aligned as the are on picture bellow, so right column aligned to right edge, and at the same time to have them aligned to left by the widthest line (texts are added dynamically, so i don't know which will be largest). I've tried constraint layout barrier, but it didn't work out very well. Is there a way to do so?

This is how i want it to look
[image]

Answer (score 0):

First off, start out with a horizontal `LinearLayout` then add 2 children Vertical `LinearLayout`.

 Add your `TextView`s on the left to the first `LinearLayout` and align the texts to the left. Do the same for the texts on the right side.
Set the `height` for the enclosing horizontal `LinearLayout` to `wrap_content` then set the `height` for the vertical `LinearLayout` containing your label on the left side to `match_parent`. On the right side, set the `height` of the vertical `LinearLayout` containing the description to `match_parent` and set the `height` of the `TextView` to `wrap_content`. Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView9"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="--- TRENER ---" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView7"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="YourOrder:" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView8"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Coach Platinum Tariff<br>shshdhshshshhs dhshshdjshdsjs" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView888"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Price:" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView88"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="30$" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I can't do that, because if there is more lines in right column, then i need to make a space i left one as well, and i don't want to change texts of titles to add empty lines on every item. And i don't know how many lines the text on right will need.

Comment: But would not this align right column to center of layout? I need the widthest textview to touch right edge of the screen (this looks ugly on tablets).

Comment: I really don't understand your comment.

Comment: Sorry. I want whole right column to be aligned to right of screen, but individual textviews to be aligned to left of the widthest of them.

Comment: The `TextView`s are aligned to the left

Comment: Nope, they are aligned to left, but on the center of screen. I want the longest to touch right side of parent, like this: [link](https://ibb.co/mLQqZ7)

Comment: Try playing with the `layout_weight` of the 2 vertical `LinearLayout`s

Comment: Its currently set 1 each which makes them both take 50% each of the parents width. Try setting the left vertical `LinearLayout`s `layout_weight` to `3`

Comment: I was thinking about that option at very beginning, but that would not be responsible to screen sizes, i would like it to be aligned exactly :/

Comment: It does deal with screen size https://lyshnia.com/images/misc/2018-04-17%2023.54.31.gif

Comment: But on large screen, there is still space between screen end and textview, and on small screen it splits to more lines that is necessary with to much empty space between columns.

Comment: Of course its not going to look the same on both small and large screen. You just have to tradeoff and choose which one would look better: Small or large screen.